# Showing required indicator on GWT's Label

Tags: java, gwt, label

In my GWT app I want to indicate the fields as required. Please advise how do I do that?

If i just add a `*` in the label text then it is not very well noticeable as it is of the same color as the label text and also aligned to the label rather like a superscript character.

I don't know if applying style sheet can make it work? Any other web 2.0 ideas which do not involve a lot of work?

Currently, it's displayed as

```
Label fullName = new Label("Full Name*");
```

Comment: Why would you think that applying a style sheet wouldn't work?

Comment: any example of css that will work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Just separate the * from the label, to another label:

```
Label label = new Label("Full name");
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
Label reqLabel = new Label("*");
reqLabel.setStyleName("red_label");
```

then on the war/app.css crete a new item

```
.red_label {
    color: red;
    font-size: 8pt;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Smething like this should work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is

```
String strReqLabel = "<span style=\"color: #DC143C;\">*</span>"

Label reqLabel = new Label(strReqLabel + " " + "First Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

Suffix the label with * mark - so that who are really cautious of filling the form will observe it and do the needful. For those you are not cautious, after submitting the form, 
you can think of making the outline in red color. This way, you need not make the form too flashy at initial look.

Answer (score 0):

So I did it as:

```
public HorizontalPanel createLabel(String name){
  HorizontalPanel hPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
  hPanel.add(new Label(name));
  Label star = new Label("*");
  star.setStyleName("req-label");
  hPanel.add(star);
  return hPanel;
}
```

and css as:

```
.req-label{
color: #FF0000;
font-weight: bold;
}
```